# LDAP not quite working for JBoss 5.x whereas it did with JBoss 4.x

Tags: jboss, ldap

We are trying to run an LDAP java program on Jboss 5.1 and authentication is failing. This same application works under Jboss 4.3 and from the command line via a JVM.

Basically there is a cookie being populated in the code. And its not working for Jboss 5.1 ONLY.

And they are using JDK 1.6.0_27.

Below is the code snippet being used for LDAP.

Why is the PagedResultsResponseControl getCookie NULL for JBoss 5.x only?? Anything change in that department?

```
        do { 
            NamingEnumeration results = ctx.search("ou=people,ou=appname,dc=dept,dc=test,dc=com", 
                    "(&(objectclass=user)(CN=*))", new SearchControls()); 
            Control[] controls = ctx.getResponseControls(); 
            if (controls != null) 
            { 
                System.out.println("if (controls != null) controls.length=" + controls.length); 
                for (int i = 0; i < controls.length; i++) 
                { 
                    if (controls[i] instanceof PagedResultsResponseControl) 
                    { 
                        PagedResultsResponseControl prrc = (PagedResultsResponseControl)controls[i]; 
                        cookie = prrc.getCookie(); /// The cookie is returned as null when run on jboss 5.1. It returns a cookie containg details of next page to be retrieved. 
                                                   // This part of the code works perfectly fine with jboss 4.3 and command line. 
                    } 
                } 
            } 
            else 
            { 
                System.out.println("No controls were sent from the server"); 
            } 
            // Re-activate paged results 
            ctx.setRequestControls(new Control[]{ 
                    new PagedResultsControl(pageSize, cookie, Control.CRITICAL) }); 

            if(cookie==null) 
            { 
                System.out.println("cookie is null"); 
            } 
            else 
            { 
                System.out.println("cookie.length= " + cookie.length + "cookie= " + cookie.toString()); 
            } 

        } while (cookie != null);
```